# How to attach a target content identifier to a shortcut item in the Info.plist?

Tags: ios, ios13

If your app supports scenes, then when the user long presses your app's icon in the Springboard and taps one of your shortcut menu items, this method is called in your scene delegate:

- `windowScene(_:performActionFor:completionHandler:)`

But is your app also supports multiple windows, the runtime needs a way to know *which* window scene's delegate to call.

To answer that question, your UIScene's `activationConditions` needs to have been set to a UISceneActivationConditions object whose `canActivateForTargetContentIdentifierPredicate` and `prefersToActivateForTargetContentIdentifierPredicate` appropriate specify predicates.
The `targetContentIdentifier` in question is a property of UIApplicationShortcutItem; it's just a string, such as `"myShortcutIdentifier"`.

The predicate's `self` *is* the incoming `targetContentIdentifier` string, so the predicate will be something like this:

```
let pred = NSPredicate(format: "self == 'myShortcutIdentifier'")
```

So far so good (as explained in https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/259/). But how to attach a target content identifier to a static UIApplicationShortcutItem defined in the *Info.plist*?

Comment: Did you ever find out how this works?

Comment: @jbehrens94 I did not. I have a bug report filed with Apple but no response so far. Seems to me that, like so much about iOS 13, they just rushed this through without thinking through the consequences.

Comment: Can I help bumping the bug report? I'd like to understand the changes for iOS 13 with scenes as well as possible, but for now it looks like we can only use dynamic quick actions.

Comment: Yes, just file your own bug report. Apple has said they respond to quantity, so the more the merrier. You do not need to reference my report by number, but it is FB7353757.

Comment: Done. Hopefully, they'll enlighten us.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the `UIApplicationShortcut​ItemTargetContentIdentifier` in the Info.plist according to [source](https://darjeelingsteve.com/articles/Advanced-Multi-window-UIs-on-iPadOS-with-Drag-and-Drop-and-State-Restoration.html).

You can then set the `can` or `prefers` cases on `UISceneActivationConditions`. This triggers the `-[UIWindowSceneDelegate windowScene:performAction​ForShortcutItem:completionHandler:]` method on `UIWindowSceneDelegate`.

Comment: Aha, cool. Has Apple got that documented? Maybe they added this since I wrote the question and filed the bug.

Comment: It isn't documented, and I'm currently trying to get this to work, but I'm starting to doubt this key works. I do receive the correct `windowScene` callback, but without targetContentIdentifier. Maybe one has to use multiple windows, but I'm still struck by how vague this whole system is.

Comment: Maybe that guy just made it up.

Comment: Or would Apple have changed this since december?

Comment: This is _exactly_ about multiple windows; that is the whole purpose of the target content identifier and my original question. If Apple doesn't document the existence of a UIApplicationShortcutItemTargetContentIdentifier key and we can't get it to work, I don't believe that this key actually exists (I mean, you can put it into your Info.plist but if the runtime disregards it, it's pointless). So I can't accept this answer as correct, so far.

Comment: There is so little info on this online that I thought I should mention that I just implemented `UIApplicationShortcut​ItemTargetContentIdentifier` in my app and it works. In my Info.plist, I give each shortcut a `UIApplicationShortcut​ItemTargetContentIdentifier` that begins with "shortcut/", e.g. "shortcut/settings". In the scene delegates for the scenes that should NOT handle the shortcut, I use the predicate "NOT self BEGINSWITH 'shortcut/'" as `canActivateForTargetContentIdentifierPredicate`.